# Multiple string replace with a Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I try to replace some multiple strings with an abbreviation `..`.
If a string occurrences more than 2 times then it is to replace with `string..string`.
E.g. the string is as follows:

```
var str = 'i,u,br,br,p,p,p,p,br,br,br,br,div,div,div,div,br,br,br,p';
// The result should be as follows:
str = 'i,u,br,br,p..p,br..br,div..div,br..br,p';
```

Here is my approach, but it doesn't work proper:

```
str = str.replace(/((,\w+)){3,}/igm, ',$1...$1');
```

Do you have any idea how can I do it right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
(\b\w+)(?:,\1){2,}
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iI9jN9/4)

What was required is for all the words to be the same, so you have to use a backreference in the pattern.

Comment: And yet still some folks claim that regular expressions are not, in fact, a dark art...

Comment: @David regexes are great once you grasp them, they can make many things so much simpler ;)

Comment: Slight issue with this - it doesn't check that the initial word is a "full" word - i.e. preceded by `,` or at the beginning of the string. e.g. `"i,u,br,br,p,p,p,p,br,br,br,br,dddiv,div,div,div,div,br,br,br,p"` will produce unexpected behavior.

Comment: Quick question, is `?:` really needed or it's only for the `.match` function to not capture this group?

Comment: @Karl-Andé it's not required at all here, it's just a simple optimization

Comment: @PaulRoub Thank you for hint. But this works: `str = str.replace(/((\w+),)\1{2,}/igm, '$2...$2,');`

Comment: @user3417601 this won't work for the last series of words because it doesn't end with a comma. My updated solution works for all cases.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yes, right! the updated answer works quite right, thanks.